# MudBlazor DataGrid - Add new record/validate record

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Getting started with Mudblazor and using their component code to create a datagrid. I'm not able to find anything that helps me add a new record and also validate the edited record.

Does anyone have any doco's they can point me to?

So far I have below which works to display and do editing, but not sure where to next.

```
   @page "/setup/vendors"



@inject VendorService _VendorService
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager


@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "PageAccessPolicy")]


<MudDataGrid T="Vendor"
            MultiSelection="false"
            Items="@theGridData"
            SortMode="SortMode.Multiple"
            Filterable="true"
            QuickFilter="@_quickFilter"
            ReadOnly="@_readOnly"
            EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Form"
            StartedEditingItem="@StartedEditingItem"
            CanceledEditingItem="@CanceledEditingItem"
            CommittedItemChanges="@CommittedItemChanges"
            Bordered="true"
            Dense="true"
            EditTrigger="DataGridEditTrigger.Manual">
   <ToolBarContent>
       <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Manage Vendors</MudText>
       <MudSpacer />
       <MudTextField @bind-Value="_searchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true"
                     AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
       <MudButton>Add New</MudButton>
   </ToolBarContent>
   <Columns>
       @*<PropertyColumn Property="x => x.VendorID" Title="VendorID" IsEditable="false"/>*@
       <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.VendorName" Title="VendorName" />
       <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Website" Title="Website" />
       <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.SalesEmail" Title="SalesEmail" />
       <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.AccountsEmail" Title="AccountsEmail" />
       <TemplateColumn CellClass="d-flex justify-end">
           <CellTemplate>
               <MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Edit" OnClick="@context.Actions.StartEditingItemAsync" />
           </CellTemplate>
       </TemplateColumn>
   </Columns>
   <PagerContent>
       <MudDataGridPager T="Vendor" />
   </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>

@code {
   private IEnumerable<Vendor> theGridData;
   private string _searchString;

   private bool _readOnly = false;

   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
       await UpdateDataAsync();
   }


   async Task UpdateDataAsync()
   {
       theGridData = await Task.Run(() => _VendorService.GetAll());
   }

   // quick filter - filter gobally across multiple columns with the same input
   private Func<Vendor, bool> _quickFilter => x =>
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_searchString))
           return true;

       if (x.VendorName.Contains(_searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           return true;

       if (x.Website.Contains(_searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           return true;


       return false;
   };

   // events
   void StartedEditingItem(Vendor item)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("In StartedEditingItem");
       // _events.Insert(0, $"Event = StartedEditingItem, Data = {System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item)}");
   }

   void CanceledEditingItem(Vendor item)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("In CanceledEditingItem");
       // _events.Insert(0, $"Event = CanceledEditingItem, Data = {System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item)}");
   }

   async Task CommittedItemChanges(Vendor item)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("In CommittedItemChanges");

       var editableItem = item;
       await _VendorService.Update(editableItem);
       await UpdateDataAsync();
       // _events.Insert(0, $"Event = CommittedItemChanges, Data = {System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item)}");
   }

}
```

Comment: This is a good question, there are some work arounds but I don't see anything natively to do this easily. Looks they only support read, update, delete at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a ref tag to the DataGrid you can manually call SetEditingItemAsync on a new object.

e.g.

```
            <MudDataGrid 
            @ref="dataGrid">
```

Then, presumably from a button OnClick handler;

```
dataGrid.SetEditingItemAsync(new Item());
```

You can then deal with it normally using CommittedItemChanges